# How to setup two laptops on a bi-direction HDMI switch with lids closed?

Tags: display, hdmi

Here's the problem, as soon as you hit the A/B button on the HDMI switch to see the other laptop's screen, and then press the A/B button to switch back again to the original laptop's screen, you find that this computer has went to sleep and doesn't wake up and only receive a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make changes to the Laptop's BIOS menu:  under "Power Mangement Options", make sure that "Deep Sleep" is unchecked, and make sure that "Wake on USB", and "Wake on Lid Open" are checked, or any other similar options that might cause a problem.

In addition, you need to setup the Windows control panel "Power Mangement Options.  Under Windows "Advanced Power Management" look for the option: "What to do when the Lid is closed". Change this option to "Do Nothing" when the power is plugged in.  You also want to set the Windows "Power Management Options" such that you laptop never goes to sleep or powers off when the power is plugged in.

Also, a "Plugable" USB 2.0 Sharing Switch works great for sharing the mouse and keyboard between the laptops in addition to the HDMI bi-directional switch. You just get one of the Logitech mouse/keyboard pair with a unifying dongle and connect it to the "Plugable USB 2.0 Sharing Switch".  You might say that all these switch boxes and cables are a big mess of wires. But really its very management if you get "double-sided mounting tape and glue the loose boxes to the table, a wall, or the back of a monitor.

To wake the other computer push the "Plugable USB 2.0 sharing switch to get to the other computer, and jiggle the mouse a little bit to activate the "Wake on USB" feature to show the monitor.